# Trouble when running checksetup.pl

Tags: installation, osx-snow-leopard, bugzilla

i am trying to install bugzilla on a mac os x snow leopard server - when i run the checksetup.pl i get this:

./localconfig: Permission denied at Bugzilla/Install/Localconfig.pm line 377,  line 253

how do i fix this and what does it mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bugzilla is trying to create a file named `localconfig` in the current directory, however you don't have access to write to that directory.

Make sure you are running checksetup.pl from the Bugzilla directory (`cd /path/to/bugzilla; ./checksetup.pl`), and your current account has write access to that directory.